# Navigation bar white space

Tags: html, css

Sorry, this is probably a really simple question, but I have searched for two days and can't seem to find the answer.  This is my first blog and I don't have any prior experience with CSS or html - just been playing with it since Sunday.  It's fun...and frustrating.

Anyhow...in my new blog for work (http://kentlawcso.blogspot.com/) I have a chunk of white space at the end of my navigation bar under the header.  I've searched the web and tried different solutions, but I can't seem to find the right balance of getting rid of the white space and not causing the "volunteer opportunities" to go to the next line (if it works in Chrome, it doesn't in IE).  The code for that bar is below.  Any thoughts on how to stretch the nav bar all the way to the right header border.  Increasing padding pushes it to the next line in some browsers too.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
#list-nav
{
padding:0;
overflow: hidden;
margin:-20;
}

#list-nav li 
{
display:inline;
}

#list-nav li a 
{   
font-family:Arial;
font-size:12px;
text-decoration: none;
float:left; 
padding:12px;
background-color: #333333;
color:#ffffff;
border-bottom:1px;
border-bottom-color:#000000;
border-bottom-style:solid;
}

#list-nav li a:hover 
{
background-color:#9B1C26;
padding-bottom:12px;
border-bottom:2px;
border-bottom-color:#000000;
border-bottom-style:solid;
margin:-1px;
}]]></b:skin>
```

Comment: in which IE version it must still work?
in ie7 evertyhing is broken - and some javascript errors are thrown

Comment: @Allison Smith - Dear there are so many issues present in css. i m working on and about to finish, can u please tell me in which browsers u r facing problems. ver please.....

Comment: I have 1 query - on hover of the menu, menus get shrink/moved little bit upwards, you have design like that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css i changed based on your problem. I have checked this in firefox.

```
.header-outer {
    background: none repeat-x scroll 0 -400px #DDDDDD;
    margin-left: 3px;
    width: 776px;
}

.tabs-inner {
    /*padding: 0 15px;*/ /* i intentionally comment this to remove the padding */
}

.section {
    /*margin: 0 15px;*/ /* i intentionally comment this to remove the margin */
}
```

Added inline style on below div (this div is just above the ul  id="list-nav")

```
<div style="width: 789px;" class="widget-content">


#list-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#list-nav li a {
    background-color: #333333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

See screen shot below for output in firefox

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  One quick question - if I make all of these adjustments, do I just leave the "#list-nav li a:hover" all the same?  It will continue to work as previously?

Comment: Hmmm, I must be doing something wrong.  I made all the changes and the entire bar was shifted to the right considerably.  I put it back to how it was...not sure what's going wrong.  Thanks for your effort.